# Check class attribute: method, attribute or nonexistent

Tags: python, oop, methods, attributes

I want my class to check if:

1. Desired attribute exist
2. If it is a method, it should return a result of method
3. If it is an attribute, return the value
4. If none exist, raise an AttributeException

My solution (not working):

```
class A:
   def __getattr__(self, item):
       try:
           return self.item()
       except AttributeError:
           try:
               return self.item
           except AttributeError:
               raise AttributeError

   y = 2
   def x(self):
     return 1
```

My test:

```
a = A()
print(a.x)
```

My result:

```
<bound method A.x of <__main__.A object at 0x7f992de18c50>>
```

As you can see, it returns a reference to the function, not its result. Where did I go wrong?

---

#### Solved

My problem is solved by using

```
@property
```

decorator.
All i wanted - to call method as property

Comment: `__getattr__` is only invoked for identifiers that aren't found the traditional way - accessing `a.x` will not call that method. Which is just as well, given that your implementation is also broken - `self.item` would be the attribute *named* `item`, not that attribute with the name of the string parameter `item`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__getattr__` is called only when the regular lookup doesn't find the item. When you lookup an item, object's `__getattribute__` is run first. If it raises `AttributeError` (it didn't find it in the object's dict) -- then it calls `__getattr__`.

The reason your code returned `bound method` is it **never executed the __getattribute__ code since the attribute is found through the regular lookup process**. Even if it were executed, it wouldn't work. `item` is a variable holding the parameter. `self.item` doesn't exist; the way to do it is using `attr = getattr(self, item)`.

What you need is `@property`, which let you access methods like they were attributes:

```
    ... class code ...

    @property
    def x(self):
        return 1

a = A()
print a.x
1
```

Note you can't call the attribute as a function anymore:

```
a.x()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\tests\test.py", line 12, in <module>
    print a.x()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the way Python works. Methods are just attributes of type bound method.

You can make this work better, but only heuristically. E.g. if you want to disallow bound methods, check for the type, and call.

However this would mean you'd get into trouble if that bound method is returned because it's supposed to be a callback provided by a property.

You can also check on the **class**-Attribute of the object if there is a property-declaration for a given name, etc.

All in all I would question your approach. There is a simple solution to this: instead of assuming what things are, let the user make that decision.

Comment: I cant figure out why it returns a bound method instead of its execution result?

Comment: As I said - you can figure that out by checking for the type "bound method". But that will be a heuristic: if the attribute is supposed to return a bound method, then you are in the next iteration of not-working-as-intended. This might or might not be a problem for your concrete use-case, but a generalisable solution does not exist.